# Autocomplete Join 2 Columns MySQL & PHP

Tags: php, mysql, autocomplete

I have a autocomplete form working by pulling the first name from the table.  However I want to autocomplete using 2 fields.  The two fields are NAME and LAST_NAME which are 2 separate fields in the database.  This is the search code I have:

```
<?php
include('db_connection.php');
if(isset($_POST['search_keyword']))
{
    $search_keyword = $dbConnection->real_escape_string($_POST['search_keyword']);
    $sqlUsers="SELECT ID, NAME, LAST_NAME FROM b_user WHERE NAME LIKE '%$search_keyword%'";
    $resUsers=$dbConnection->query($sqlUsers);

    if($resUsers === false) {
        trigger_error('Error: ' . $dbConnection->error, E_USER_ERROR);
    }else{
        $rows_returned = $resUsers->num_rows;
    }

$bold_search_keyword = '<strong>'.$search_keyword.'</strong>';
if($rows_returned > 0){
        while($rowUsers = $resUsers->fetch_assoc()) 
        { 
            echo '<div class="show" align="left"><span class="user_name">'.str_ireplace($search_keyword,$bold_search_keyword,$rowUsers['NAME']).'</span></div>'; 
        }
    }else{
        echo '<div class="show" align="left">No matching records.</div>'; 
    }
} 
?>
```

The above code returns the first name in the dropdown fine but I need the it to search the NAME and then continue on to the LAST_NAME.  Is there a way of joining the NAME and LAST_NAME.  I have tried this:

```
 $sqlUsers="SELECT ID, CONCAT(NAME, ' ', LAST_NAME) AS FULLNAME FROM b_user WHERE FULLNAME LIKE '%$search_keyword%'";
```

And then display:

```
 <span class="user_name">'.str_ireplace($search_keyword,$bold_search_keyword,$rowUsers['FULLNAME']).'</span>
```

But this seems to break the search completely.  I feel I'm not far off with the above but not joy yet.  Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting any error

Comment: In the console I just get an Internal Server error on the POST relating to this file.

Comment: Then there's a PHP error within your code need to check. Post entire code for `<span class="user_name">'.str_ireplace($search_keyword,$bold_search_keyword,$rowUsers['FULLNAME']).'</span>
`

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your NAME and LAST_NAME separate in the query, which gives you greater control on how to output the results for the autocomplete.  You just need to change the WHERE clause of your query to also find matches on the last name.  I think auto-completes are usually very loosely matched, this might work.

```
SELECT ID, NAME, LAST_NAME FROM b_user WHERE NAME LIKE '%$search_keyword%' OR LAST_NAME LIKE '%$search_keyword%'
```